# Elasticsearch won't run with Docker

Tags: java, elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch-5

I wrote some code that integrates with Elasticsearch, and it worked fluently when ES was running on my computer. However, when I tried to run ES through Docker I keep getting this error again and again:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{hrmyFR97S_qMsPEsOOEFjw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

This is how I initialize the client:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch123")
                .build();

 Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

And this is what my docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:
      elastic3:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
        environment:
          - cluster.name=elasticsearch123
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - transport.host=127.0.0.1
          - xpack.security.enabled=false
          - http.host=0.0.0.0
          - network.host=127.0.0.1

        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
          - "9300:9300"
        volumes:
         - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

And here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>`
```

Any ideas? I really have no ideas left!

Comment: Sorry it dosent concerned your question but i am trying to get to interact with elastic search using java but i am not able to do it can you help me on this . any git hub repo and all i am not able to fetch and update

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is all about wrong network configuration. Check network operation modes and ajust to use `host` insteed of default `bridge`. Moreover you will not need to "expose" prots as all ports will be exposed out of the box. It is because docker container will bind directy you hots's interface insteed of virtual one.

Check `Network settings` section in

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification

As you are using `compose` here you have proper config option

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networkmode